# test.setMock issue passing a parameter

Tags: apex, unit-test, api, mock

I'm having difficulty passing a paramater to a HttpCalloutMock class. I have a trigger that calls a future callout on insert and on the response I'm receiving the record id so I can do the relevant record updates. this works fine but when I try to test it I can't pass the Id of the record to the mock class as I'm declaring it before I insert it. Am I going about it the wrong way or is there a workaround? here is the code snippet:

```
@isTest
public static void testNewCaseInsert(){

    Id user = [SELECT id FROM User WHERE FirstName = 'TestUser' LIMIT 1].id;

    Id myPlusRTypeId    = [SELECT id FROM RecordType WHERE developerName = 'Test_Plus' LIMIT 1].id;

    Id contactId = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE FirstName = 'Contact' LIMIT 1].id;

    Case caseMPlus        = new Case(

        RecordTypeId         =  myPlusRTypeId,
        OwnerId              =  user,
        Status               = 'New',
        Priority             = 'Medium',
        ContactId            =  contactId,
        Origin               = 'Email',
        Subject              = 'Subject Mail Plus',
        Description          = 'watermelons',
     );

    test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockResponse(caseMPlus.id));//I can't pass case Id without inserting it first

    test.startTest();
        insert caseMPlus;
    test.stopTest();

   }
```

And here is the Mock class:

```
@isTest
public class LimitlessMockResponse implements HttpCalloutMock {

    protected Id caseId;

    public LimitlessMockResponse(Id caseId){

        this.caseId = caseId;

    }


    public HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        System.assertEquals('callout:Limitless', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //trying to pass the caseId into the body to assert against the response
        res.setBody('{"count": 1,"success": 1,"failed": 0,"messages": [{"tenantMsgId":'+'"'+caseId+'","rejectReasonCode": "no group found","processCode": "ACC"}]}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }

}
```

Here is the logic part:

```
public static void handleResponse(String rBody){

    List<Case>updateCases = new List<Case>();

    LimitlessDataResponse dResponse = LimitlessDataResponse.parse(rBody);

        //Loop through the cases on the response and update 
        for(DataResponse.Messages r : dResponse.messages){
         //Here is where I'm using the case Id from the response to matchup against
                Case c = new case (id = r.tenantMsgId,
                                   Sync_Status__c = r.processCode == 'ACC' ? 'Synced' : 'Failed',
                                   Sync_Failed_Reason__c = r.rejectReasonCode,
                                   Retry__c = FALSE
                                   );

                system.debug('ResponseData:'+ r.processCode +'  '+r.tenantMsgId);

                updateCases.add(c);
        }   
    if(!updateCases.isEmpty()){

        try{

            update updateCases;

        }catch(DmlException e){

            system.debug('There was an error handling the reponse:'+ e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why does the Id matter?

Comment: i'm posting case details on another system, and with the resulting response I want to update the case with a "Success" or "Fail" field. I added the code snippet for that part of the logic at the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test the fact that your trigger makes a callout and the handling of that callout separately. A more testable structure would look something like:

```
public with sharing class CaseTriggerHandler
{
    @TestVisible static Boolean bypassTrigger;

    final List<Case> newRecords;
    final Map<Id, Case> oldMap;
    public CaseTriggerHandler(List<Case> newRecords, Map<Id, Case> oldMap)
    {
        this.newRecords = newRecords;
        this.oldMap = oldMap;
    }

    public void afterInsert()
    {
        if (bypassTrigger) return;

        // optionally filter a collection of records
        // for which a callout is necessary
        Set<Id> recordIds = new Map<Id, Case>(newRecords).keySet();
        CaseService.makeSomeCallout(recordIds);
    }
}
```

Your trigger would call this handler somewhat like so:

```
CaseTriggerHandler handle = new CaseTriggerHandler(trigger.new, trigger.oldMap);

if (trigger.isAfter)
{
    if (trigger.isInsert) handle.afterInsert();
}
```

Now testing the trigger itself is a cinch. Just make sure a callout is made.

```
@IsTest
class CaseTriggerTests
{
    static testmethod void testTrigger_InsertCallout()
    {
        List<Case> records = new List<Case>();
        // populate collection with a bunch of data

        Test.startTest();
            // set any mock
            insert records;
            Integer callouts = Limits.getCallouts();
        Test.stopTest();

        system.assertEquals(1, callouts, 'A singe callout should be made');
    }
}
```

As for testing the callout itself, you can disable the trigger, insert some records, and then make your call and verify the handler method does what it is supposed to.

```
// testing CaseService
static testmethod void testMakeSomeCallout()
{
    CaseTriggerHandler.bypassTrigger = true;

    Case record = new Case(/*requisite data*/);
    insert record;

    CaseTrigger.bypassTrigger = false;
    // best to turn the trigger back on

    Test.startTest();
        // set your mock with the proper Id here here
        CaseService.makeSomeCallout(new Set<Id>{record.Id});
    Test.stopTest();

    // assert the record was updated correctly
}
```

Please note you have an empty catch block. That is a *very bad idea* and may cause you to spend hours tearing your hair out trying to figure out why an isolated test is failing. **Always make sure your catch blocks have side-effects which you can assert against.** Otherwise remove the catch block entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the help! this worked and you made it simple to understand

Comment: @JPG Glad I could help. Please do note that last paragraph and remove your empty catch block. Otherwise some developer in 6 months is going to be very upset (maybe yourself).